# How do I fix an Access Violation Error in C++

Tags: c++, access-violation

I have an assignment in which I have to take an array and reverse it's order. We are supposed to use pointers to accomplish this but I'm having trouble with one part of my code. On line 26 I'm trying to reassign the array element to a new value but when I try I get an Access Violation Error "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF60459600D in HW7_JacobS.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000."

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

void swap_elements(int *array, size_t size);

int main(void) {
    puts("Enter elements of the array and the code will reverse the array.");
    int array[SIZE];
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("Enter element %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    } 
    puts("Array before reversing:");
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%5d", array[i]);
    } puts("");
    swap_elements(*array, SIZE);
 }

void swap_elements(int *array, size_t size) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= size / 2; i++) {
        int *element1Ptr = &array[i - 1];
        int *element2Ptr = &array[-1];
        int val1 = element1Ptr;
        int val2 = element2Ptr;
        array[i - 1] = val1; // Here is the problem
        array[-i] = val2;
    }
    puts("Array after reversing:");
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%5d", array[i]);
    }
}
```

I was expecting the code to reassign array[i - 1] to val1 but instead the code breaks and gives this error in debug mode.

Comment: `&array[-1];` is out of bounds. So is `array[-i]`. I don't understand what you're hoping to achieve with the pointers in `swap_elements` either.

Comment: There's nothing C++ in the code you show, it could all be plain C. And as such there's nothing that ties this to the C++17 standard. At most you should label it only as C++, but even that is a stretch IMO. What resources are you using to learn C++?

Comment: This won't compile as C++ and even though it will as C you should be receiving multiple compile warnings you must pay attention to. If not you need to adjust your compile settings. https://godbolt.org/z/qe7z9zsKs

Comment: `array[-1]` works in python but it is invalid in C++, you must use `array[size-1]` instead.

Comment: To do it with pointers, create a pointer to the first element and a pointer to the last element. If the two pointers have met, you're done. Otherwise swap the values at the two pointers. Increment the first pointer and decrement the last pointer. Go back to "If the two pointers have met...".

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. Fix the warnings. That should help. Here: `swap_elements(*array, SIZE);` you are passing the first element of the array by value which is then being interpreted as a pointer on the other end.

Comment: One complication in the `swap_elements` function (after fixing the out-of-bound addressing) is that it uses two different techniques to visit elements of the array. `element1Ptr` points at the `i-1`th element; `array[i - 1]` is the `i-1`th element. Pick an approach: either use pointers to access elements or use indices. Since your assignment is to use pointers, that's what you should do. `int val1 = *element1Ptr; ... *element1Ptr = val2;`.

Answer (score 0):

This is C code, and you likely compile it as C if your file had `.c` extension. `swap_elements(*array, SIZE);` is giveaway, result of `*array` is an `int`ad you're trying tocast if from pointer. A C compiler will tell you:

```
prog.c:18:19: warning: passing argument 1 of 'swap_elements' 
makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

From here on your code WILL cause UB, e.g.  address violation, becuase  `swap_elements` accesses some non-existing object.

In C++ this code won't compile at all because of multiple errors.

While `array[-i]` is a correct syntax , it assumes `*(array-i)` being a correct location, but in your case `array` points at the beginning of array. Negative index in C and C++ doesn't do what it does in Python.